# React native Webview auto login

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I am new to react native and first time using the `react-native-webview`. We already have website now I tried the develop the app for the website.

My issue was when I try to open the URL in webview it asking the credentials to login the page. but I have already login in the mobile, now I tried to open any website URL in webview it again asking the credentials to login.

I have searched in google but I don't have any clue.

Can anyone please let me know how to solve this issue or sent the login credentials to webview and open the URL.

```
<WebView
          source={{ uri: URL }}
          startInLoadingState={true}
          renderLoading={() => 
            <ActivityIndicator
            color={theme.colors.accent}
            size="large"
            style={styles.activityIndicator} />
          }
        />
```

Comment: maybe you can use postMessage method of webview. and catch login credentials inside webview. this can give idea https://medium.com/@azharuddin31/react-native-pass-data-to-webview-and-get-data-out-of-webview-792ffbe7eb75

Answer (score 0):

Try to set localStorage webview a token

> let setLocalStorage = `(function(){  window.localStorage.setItem('token', '${accessToken}'); })();`;

in webview add this

> injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded={setLocalStorage}

Comment: Thanks for your response. but I have fixed another way.

Comment: I am also looking for the same functionality. Can u give an idea of how u did it?